# How can I call a method into a function of another method?

Tags: php, function, methods

[Here](https://3v4l.org/E1U9n) is my code:

```
class myclass{

    public function one(){
        return 'sth';
    }

    public function two(){
        function myfunc($arg){
            if ($arg){
                return $this->one();
            } else {
                return 'nothing';
            }
            myfunc(true);
        }
    }
}

$obj = new myclass;
echo $obj->$this->two();
```

As you see in the fiddle it throws this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /in/E1U9n:25

How can I fix the problem?  The expected result is `sth`.

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment and explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: what happens if you change echo $obj->$this->two(); to `echo $obj->two();`

Comment: @PavelJanicek In your case the error will be gone https://3v4l.org/bhSiL. But why `sth` will not be printed?

Comment: Honestly no idea. To my knowledge it should return something...

Comment: Also, I highly recommend to edit this question to newer one, because this one can be "solved" by removing one typo error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First you're calling myfunc(true); in it's own scope.So it is not
   possible to call a function in it's scope as far as i know
2. Secondly You're calling $this in a scope of function which doesn't know which class does it belong.
3. Thirdly you're not returning anything from your function two() so as it suppose. It will not echo anything.
4. See the fiddle https://3v4l.org/sl4eq

   ```
   class myclass{

       public function one(){
           return 'sth';
       }

       public function two(){
           function myfunc($arg){
               if ($arg){
                   $newobj = new myclass();
                   return $newobj->one();
               } else {
                   return 'nothing';
               }

           }
           return myfunc(TRUE);
       }
   }


   $obj = new myclass;
   echo $obj->two();
   ```

Comment: Yes. I just found out the same. Bravo! Have my upvote

Comment: Good one @MartinAJ

Answer (score 1):

Your code is really messy, because you lack of basic knowledge and experience. I strictly recommending for you to read the basics about OOP in PHP.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

```
<?php

class myclass {

    public function one()
    {
        return 'sth';
    }

    public function two()
    {
        return $this->myfunc(true);
    }

    protected function myfunc($arg)
    {
        if ($arg)
            return $this->one();
        else
            return 'nothing';
    }

}

$obj = new myclass;
echo $obj->two();
```